# ¿Es posible integrar un array a una consulta mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

dado el siguiente arreglo:

```
$tablas= array("honda_firme","honda_service_parts","honda_oe");
```

es posible a gragarlo a una consulta y con in ciclo FOR recorrerlo y que en cada iteracion cambie de tabla la consulta, tengo una vaga idea pero no logro concretarla estoy retomando la progrmacion y estoy algo oxidado tengo este avance.

```
   $cuentaParts=1;
   $tablas= array("honda_firme","honda_service_parts","honda_oe"); // contador y arreglo
   $contador=0;
   for($i=1; $i<=(3*$numModel); $i++){
     if($contador==count($model)){
         $contador=0;
     }
    list ($nombre,$nopart)=explode("_",$model[$contador]);
    $contador++;

    // consulta 
    $qryhondamulti=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tablas[$contador]." WHERE CAST(fecha_entrega_xml AS DATE)= '$fechaMod' ORDER BY fecha_entrega_xml ASC, id_archivo DESC")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Si las tablas son clones pero con diferentes filas o vas a traer los mismos tipos de datos quizas lo mas optimo seria hacer UNION, pero faltaria contexto para darte una respuesta clara.

Comment: Las tablas tienen diferentes columnas salvo por la que estoy haciendo referencia en el WHERE es decir las 3 tablas tienen la misma columna (fecha_entrega_xml) utilizo el CAST ya que en 2 de ellas tienen formato datetime y la restante el formato es time solamente, investigare sobre tu sugerencia UNION ya que estoy empezando de nuevo y necesito un F5

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Lo que ya tienes va bien, pero falta que el mysql_query lo incluyas dentro del ciclo FOR que dices:

```
  // consulta 
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($tablas); $i++)
  {
    $qryhondamulti=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tablas[$i]." WHERE CAST(fecha_entrega_xml AS DATE)= '$fechaMod' ORDER BY fecha_entrega_xml ASC, id_archivo DESC")or die(mysql_error());
  }
```

Claro que si tienes ese die(), me temo que si una de las consultas se cae, te saldrías del FOR? Eso no lo tengo claro, ya que nunca uso el die() -_-...

Igual puedes hacer el ciclo con un FOREACH que es más amigable :)

Comment: el die() lo utilizo regularmente solo por razones de prueba, cuando obtengo los reultados deseados casi siempre los dejo en comentario, es buena tu sugerencia pero la consulta si esta dentro del ciclo FOR que uso.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que todo el código que pusiste está dentro del ciclo FOR? ....Tienes razón... es que falta el último paréntesis de cierre XDDD jejeje...

Comment: Y al ejecutar este ciclo, ¿no estás obteniendo los resultados que esperas? Digo, porque sin entender ni saber de qué van todas las otras variables y procesos que haces previo a cada llamada a mysql_query, me parece que está correcto el código... Mi sugerencia es que vayas imprimiendo en pantalla a cada variable en tu ciclo ($i, $numModel, $contador, $model, etc....).

Comment: si, despues de la consulta tengo un while para poder imprimir los resultados y despues de eso cierro el cilco FOR ( } ) ... XD

Comment: Tiene razon, hay algunas variables de la cuales no explico su uso y asi es casi imposible formular alguna idea, voy editar el codigo con comentarios para ver si me explico mejor